# generating java entities from MySQL tables

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, spring-boot

I have 3 MySQL tables and i need to generate their corresponding entities in java (eclipse)
is there an easy way ?
im working on a spring boot application

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/docs/3.2/user_guide/tasks006.htm)

Comment: @Sudoss i did i couldn't find the jpa tools...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the majority of people will recommend jpa(spring data) this is codeFirst approach, for DB first approach I have a great framework recommendation:

If you have some time on your hand I will go and try Jooq

[Jooq website](https://www.jooq.org/)

Jooq has a maven dependency for creating all necessary objects from your db:

[Jooq auto code generation from db](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.13/manual/code-generation/codegen-maven/)

[codeGen configuration in maven](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.13/manual/code-generation/codegen-configuration/)

Jooq can connect to your db, and even connect to your liquibase schema upgrades so that the object are always on the same stage with the db

I don't have any connection to Jooq but Lukas Eder (@lukaseder) is an awsome guy, he always answer questions in stack Overflow, so you are in good hands, also if you are using reactor Jooq is fully compatible(also compatible with JavaRX)